# Rails - grouping by day for the last week

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to create an array that has the total of all sales a company does for each day of the week. Right now I have something similar to this

```
@sales = Sale.all
@sales_total = @sales.map{|sale|sale.total.to_i}
```

Which returns an array of each total for every single sale.

Before turning it into an array, how can I group Sale by day, and adding total together?

Comment: Have you considered [Enumerable#group_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by)?

Comment: better to do this with SQL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm a fan of [groupdate](https://github.com/ankane/groupdate) gem.

You ca do something like:

```
@sales_total = Sale.group_by_day(:created_at).order("day asc").sum(:total)
```

Assuming `total` is the column you want to sum up.

**EDIT** - To add a interval of time condition you can use `where`, for example:

```
@sales_total = Sale.where('created_at between ? and ?', Date.today, 1.week.ago).group_by_day(:created_at).order("day asc").sum(:total)
```

Comment: That gem looks interesting. How would I limit the days so it only groups the days from last week or last month?

Comment: Not sure if its a problem with the gem but I'm getting "Connection adapter not supported: SQLite"